# Splitting strings in R and extracting information from lists

Tags: r

I have the following row names in my data:

```
column_01.1
column_01.2
column_01.3
column_02.1
column_02.2
```

I can split these rownames with the following command:

```
strsplit(rownames(my_data),split= "\\.")
```

and get the list:

```
[[1]]
[1] "column_01" "1"   

[[2]]
[1] "column_01" "2"   

[[3]]
[1] "column_01" "3"

...
```

But since I want characters out of the first part and completely discard the second part, like this:

```
column_01
column_01
column_01
column_02
column_02
```

I have run out of tricks to extract only this part of the information. I've tried some options with unlist() and as.data.frame(), but no luck. Or is there an easier way to split the strings? I do not want to use `as.character(substring(rownames(my_data),1,9))` as the location of the "." can change (while it would work for this example).

Comment: Another approach is using the `colsplit` function in the `reshape2` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can map `[` to get the first elements:

```
sapply(strsplit(rownames(my_data),split= "\\."),'[',1)
```

...or (better) use regular expressions:

```
gsub('\\..*$','',rownames(my_data))
```

(translation: find all matches of (dot-character, something, end-of-string) and replace with empty string)

Answer (score 0):

Since I like the `stringr` package, I thought I'd throw this out there:

```
str_replace(rownames(my_data), "(^column_.+)\\.\\d+", "\\1")
```

(I'm not great with regex so the `^` might be better outside the parenthesis)